# How to set Alice as author in the mock.rs for testing?

Tags: testing

I want to test my pallet that get digest info to collect the author of the current block.
So, is it possible to set, for example, Alice as a block author in the mock.rs so I can test it?

I set up the mock.rs in [this way](https://github.com/Datagen-Project/Datagen-Substrate-Grant/blob/testing_pallet_computational_work/fast_blockchain/pallets/computational-work/src/mock.rs) configuring `pallet_session`, `pallet_node_authorization` and `pallet_aura`.

but when I try to call a test with `cargo test`:

```rust
#[test]
fn hash_work() {
    new_test_ext().execute_with(|| {

        run_to_block(10);
        assert_ok!(ComputationalWork::hash_work(Origin::signed(get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Alice"))));
    })
}
```

I get this error:

```shell
thread 'tests::check_x_block_index_change_by_1' panicked at 'called `Option::unwrap()` on a `None` value', pallets/computational-work/src/lib.rs:140:62
```

the lines that cause the error:

```rust
// Get the block author.
let block_digest = <frame_system::Pallet<T>>::digest();
let digests = block_digest.logs.iter().filter_map(|d| d.as_pre_runtime());
let author = T::FindAuthor::find_author(digests).unwrap();
```

I think the problem is author that is none in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add these to your mock file.

```rust
impl pallet_computational_work::Config for Test {
    type Event = Event;
    type FindAuthor = AuthorGiven;
}

pub struct AuthorGiven;
impl frame_support::traits::FindAuthor<YourAccountIdType> for AuthorGiven {
    fn find_author<'a, I>(digests: I) -> Option<YourAccountIdType>
    where
        I: 'a + IntoIterator<Item = (sp_runtime::ConsensusEngineId, &'a [u8])>,
    {
        Some(AliceOrAnyYouWant)
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok it's working, thank you!